# React-Native : Orientation becomes locked on mount of signature component

Tags: android, react-native, orientation

I am using [react-native-signature-capture](https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) for sign purpose.

```
<RNSignatureCapture
    onSaveEvent={(result) => this.onSignatureSave(result)}
    saveImageFileInExtStorage={false}
    showNativeButtons={false}
    viewMode={this.state.landscapeMode ? "landscape" : "portrait"}
/>
```

`ViewMode` determines the orientation of the screen. But the problem is after first render of the `RNSignatureCapture` total app gets locked to the same orientation as given in `ViewMode`. The only possible way to get rid  of it is deleting the app.

Is there any way for auto orientation according to device movement once the `RNSignatureCapture` is unmounted?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

if `ViewMode` props is not provided then app won't get locked to particular orientation.